Skip-Gram Model description in word2vec explanation article
In his article word2vec Parameter Learning Explained Xin Rong says (page 7):

Each output is computed using the same hidden->output matrix:


Looking into the word2vec source code I don’t see any “panels” or “output layers”, although I see that the code uses a “window” of words for which neu1e is calculated which later updates the syn0. So, I assume that this is exactly what the second part of the equation above does (taking into account hierarchical softmax) and the “panel” in the text above is somewhat “virtual”. Please, correct me if I am wrong here.
If this formula and mu understanding correct, with the description above from the article, since

the output layer panels share the same weights

how the results on output panels (even if they existed could be different)? What would exactly be different with the same given input word and same weights?

It's tough to guess what this author meant by "panels", as I've not seen that as a common term in other word2vec writeups or source code. Checking the original author's related demo/docs/source-code (eg starting from https://ronxin.github.io/wevi/) might offer more insight into their way of understanding word2vec.

@gojomo, I glanced his code when I read the article, it doesn’t have any panels, as well. Most likely, this is addressed in the chapter 3, “Optimizing Computational Efficiency” where it is said that due to efficiency optimization tricks output vectors are placed in hierarchical softmax tree and most likely they are updated only with a kind of average accumulation, so the panels “optimized out” and exist in the paper for explanation purposes only. The trick which is hard to grasp at once when something missing in code, in final description and comes virtually only in the middle of the text.

Since the code reflects what widely-used/deployed implementations actually do, I personally think it's more important to understand than the papers. The main trick of hierarchical softmax is that by training the output nodes to huffman-code-signal a target word, training only needs to nudge the small set of nodes involved in the encoding, rather than all, for a massive training speedup over pure softmax. Negative sampling similarly uses the shortcut that works well in practice of just adjusting one node for the target word & N random other 'negative' word nodes.

In practice, I see negative-sampling used more often – it seems to do as well or better than HS as training data  grow – and large training data is the key to the quality of all word2vec's results. Negative sampling also doesn't cause training to necessarily get a bit slower per example with larger vocabularies (unless you want to increase the count of N negative samples for other reasons).

@gojomo, thank you for the detailed comments. It helps. I have to say that I understand the word2vec inside out since I had implemented the similar things years before the original algorithm, so I understand how and why they do things. My goals here is to learn math description since most of the recent articles are more math-based than algorithm-based, and I decided to grasp math approach on the familiar material where I know how the code works. So, here in order to put things together I want to understand the paper up to the last letter. Just to grasp the math language and approach.

@gojomo, (continue) with the recent findings I understood that there is a difference between math description (or vision) and real implementation not only because of optimization tricks, but just because some math essences are not necessary to implement. They exist only as some terms and abstractions (like the probability in formula above), but it is not necessary to reflect them in code.

@gojomo, (continue). The “panels” here verge these two things, abstractions and optimizations. That was the only my concern in the formula. I was wondering, why going from existing code he introduced the thing that doesn’t exist in the code. And now I see that this is the only way to get to full consistent math description here.
